# MySQL: Full-Text inflectional forms of words?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

### Is it possible to execute FTS queries using Forms of words inflectional?
For example:
select id, string from test;

1  John worked as chief and works as pilot
2  George works as pilot
3  Mary likes flowers

and search something like
select id, string from test where string .... 'work';
and receive 2 rows with id in (1,2)

?

Comment: What you want is called "stemming." MySQL FULLTEXT doesn't do it inherently but there are workarounds.

Comment: Yes, may be, I have used as in SQL Server. What are workarounds?

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate question.